# Unable to mount NAS

Tags: raspbian, mount

I unsuccessfully trying to mount NAS attached to Netgear router.

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.1/shares /media/shared
```

Comes back with:

```
Password for root@//192.168.1.1/shares:
Retrying with upper case share name
mount error(6): No such device or address
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

Even though i can access it using:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/media $ smbclient -L //192.168.1.1/shares
Enter pi's password: 
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.0.24]

Sharename       Type      Comment
---------       ----      -------
USB_Storage     Disk      
IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (NETGEAR R6100)
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.0.24]
...
```

NAS is not password protected.

Answer (score 1):

It was my mistake assuming `smbclient -L` needed a valid path to return the response. The actual path was

```
//192.168.1.1/USB_Storage
```